# changing line \n doesn't work

Tags: python, line

My `\n` doesn`t work
Here's my code:

```
s = 0
a = 0
w = 0
h = 0
stats = "1. Strength - ", s, "\n2. Agility - ", a, "\n3. Wisdom - ", w, "\n4. Health - ", h
print(stats)
```

When trying start program i get this:

```
('1. Strength - ', 0, '\n2. Agility - ', 0, '\n3. Wisdom - ', 0, '\n4. Health - ', 0)
```

btw, I need my `s`, `a`, `w`, `h` variables as integer.

Comment: If this is python3.x , you can simply do - `print(*stats)` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar, thanks, it works.

Comment: The reason for this is that you are storing 'stats' as a tuple, not a string.  So when you print it, it's printing a tuple.  The * operator Anand suggested unpacks the tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Liturgist** awnser is a approach to print a tuple of values like you have, but i think you want to concatenate them. don use `,` to concatenation, `+` its for these purpose. My alernative aproach.

```
stats = "1. Strength - " +str(s)+ "\n"+"2. Agility - "+ str(a)+ "\n" + "3. Wisdom - "+  str(w) + "\n" + "4. Health - "+ str(h)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is printing the list exactly as you have created it. If you want to see each item separately:

```
>>> for s in (stats): print(s)
...
1. Strength -
0

2. Agility -
0

3. Wisdom -
0

4. Health -
0
```